# Is it possible to truncate a polar plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that I would like to display in a polar plot. The data, when displayed, is asymmetric with respect to the origin leaving lots of blank space. I would like to remove the blank space and have a plot that contains just the data.

For example the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x

theta = np.arange(0, 6*np.pi, .01)[1:]

plt.polar(theta, f(theta))
plt.ylim([0,2])
```

produces the following plot

[image]

but I would rather it looked like:

[image]

Also I would like to be able to change the orientation of the radial tick marks from the default so that they are completely vertical instead of at an angle.

**EDIT** - images now inline

Comment: [how-do-i-display-image-in-a-post-on-stack-overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106053/how-do-i-display-image-in-a-post-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: There is no easy built-in way to do that. But if you look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html) pretty much everything is possible.

Comment: Ok thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I will have a look at the example and post back if I figure something out.